# gatting invalid type error in react native while type is correct

Tags: react-native

I'm using `useState` to set value like this

```
  const [number, setNumber] = useState('');
```

and here is my input

```
<TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Enter Number 03********"
          keyboardType="phone-pad"
          textAlign={'center'}
          selectionColor="#1e2d50"
          maxLength={11}
          value={number}
          onChange={(e) => setNumber(e)}
        />
```

When I give input I get this error

```
 Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` of type `object` supplied to `ForwardRef(TextInput)`, expected `string`.
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Have you imported the TextInput from react-native or created a custom TextInput Component?

Comment: imported from react-native

Comment: can you try by removing the value property from text input, are you still getting this issue or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react- native, the textInput value expects a string not a number. if you want to provide a number as value you first need to convert it to string;

```
<TextInput ... value={String(number)} onChangeText={text => setNumber(text)} />
```

Comment: I'm getting `[object Obj` in input by default and i'm unable to input anthing. whenever i type input is overwritten by above snippet.

Comment: Because you are using onchange and you are directly passing the whole e to be setted as a number. You need to use onChangeText instead of onChange. Please check my answer again. I will make some more edits.

Comment: Note that onChange does not return the text only written in the TextInput, but it returns an objects containing many more data about the input field but onChangeText returns only the text.